# C# Impossible to convert method group to bool?

Tags: c#

```
      public void nbOccurences(int[] base1, int n, int m)
     {
         foreach (int i in base1)
         {
             if (n == 32)
             {
                 m++;
             }
         }
     }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int chiffrebase = 32;
        int occurence = 0;
        int[] test123 = new int[] { 12, 32, 33, 64, 75, 46, 42, 32 };
        Program n1 = new Program();
        n1.nbOccurences(test123, chiffrebase, occurence);
        Console.WriteLine(nbOccurences);
    }
```

I keep getting a "Impossible to convert from method group to bool" message, what's causing the problem? I'm trying to use the method I made in the main program.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `Console.WriteLine(nbOccurences);`?

Comment: it looks like you want to return the value of `m`. You should do that by making `nbOccurrences` `public int nbOccurrences` and `return m;` at the end. Then, assign the result by doing `int occurences = n1.nbOccurrences(test123, chiffrebase);`. Finally, do `Console.WriteLine(occurrences);`. The problem is that your method has no output, so it can't give anything to the `WriteLine` function that will be sent to the console (how does it know what to put there?). And also, `nbOccurrences` by itself doesn't *run* the function, just names it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(nbOccurences);
```

`nbOccurrences` is a mehtod (returning void, by the way). 
so compiler complains saying "I need something to print on writeline, maybe you want me to print a bool, but I can't convert a method to a bool"

Also, your `nbOccurrences` seems to do nothing useful: it iterates on an Array, checks some condition and eventually increase the parameter value. But calling code will not be aware of the m value, which remains internal to your function. You should change your method declaration returning an `int` (or using an `out int m` parameter, which would not be my choice)

Answer (score 2):

This is my best guess as to what you're actually aiming at:

```
public int nbOccurrences(int[] base1, int n)
{
   int count = 0;
   foreach (int i in base1)
   {
      if (n == 32)
      {
         count++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int chiffrebase = 32;
    int[] test123 = new int[] { 12, 32, 33, 64, 75, 46, 42, 32 };
    int occurrences = nbOccurrences(test123, chiffrebase, occurrence);
    Console.WriteLine(occurrences);
}
```

Your method `nbOccurrences` didn't return anything before, so how can it be used to do anything? There *is* a way to use an `out` or `ref` parameter to get values back from method via parameters, but *you should NOT do that until you are much more expert*.

The `WriteLine` method is looking for a `string` or something that can be converted to a string or have `ToString` run on it. Instead, you gave it the name of a method (not the result of a method call, the method itself). How would it know what to do with that?

One invokes a method using parentheses, so pay careful attention to note that `nbOccurrences` is NOT the same thing as `nbOccurrences()`.

Finally, I'm gambling that you do NOT need `new Program`. It *works*, but probably isn't what you want. Instead, just call the method which is in the current, same program as the one you're running, `Program`.

Finally, while this may be too soon in your C# journey, note that this same task can be performed this way (add `using System.Linq;`):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int chiffrebase = 32;
    int[] test123 = new int[] { 12, 32, 33, 64, 75, 46, 42, 32 };
    int occurrences = test123.Count(i => i == chiffrebase);
    Console.WriteLine(occrurences);
}
```

P.S. *Occurrences* is spelled with two Rs. Not one.

Answer (score 1):

The Console.WriteLine function has many overloads, one of which is expecting a bool as a parameter. 
When you call a function like this

```
 Console.WriteLine(1);
```

the compiler determines which version of the function you want to call (in my above example it should be the int version.

In your sample code, you simply need to add some brackets so it looks like this if you wanted to call the function.
It's worth noting that your nbOccurrences function does not actually return a value (it's return type is void) so this will likely still fail.

```
Console.WriteLine(nbOccurences());
```